# Apollo Client Mutation get an error 400 with React Component

Tags: graphql, next.js, react-apollo, apollo-client

> **Mutation gql tag:**

```
// AppAdminLoinInput is wrong spell don't focus it.
const LOGIN_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation AppAdminLoinInput($email: String!, $password: String!) {
    appAdminLogin(email: $email, password: $password) {
      name
      email
      token {
        accessToken
        refreshToken
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

> **Mutation Function onSubmit**

```
onSubmitLogin = async (e, appAdminLogin) => {
    const { email, password } = this.state;

    e.preventDefault();

    if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
      console.log("Not email format");
      return;
    }

    if (password.length < 8) {
      return;
    }

    appAdminLogin({
      variables: {
        email,
        password
      }
    });
  };
```

When onSubmitLogin do i get an error 400 (Bad request)
What am i do wrong?
sorry about my english skill xD

Comment: A 400 status means your query is invalid. Please check the actual response from the server in your browser's dev tools -- it will contains an `errors` array with the reason the query is invalid.

Comment: I already solved it, I got wrong of mutation function. Thanks